# How do you do vertical text in Firefox?

Tags: css

I want it to start from the bottom and go up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

I can't remember if the CSS supports radians, but that may work as well. Of course, defining pi might be an issue!

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="rotate">
Text
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rotate{-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);}
```

Answer (score 0):

For firefox

```
.verticaltext {
```

`writing-mode: tb-rl;`
`filter: flipV flipH;`
`}`

Comment: This is now in firefox 36. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode